# Nested for-each for double matching

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am struggling to find correct approach for the problem I am facing.
I need to update 'color' node of 'xml1', with attribute 'colorDef' of product element in 'xml2'

The matching of 'xml1' and 'xml2' via 'prodId' attribute that exists in both xmls (option: many-to-many), but there is additional requirement:

I need to update only specific 'citem' (not all), need to update 'citem' element where sub-element 'type' equals to 'FavType' element.

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product prodId="390">
        <FavType>XX2</FavType>
        <citem>
            <type>XX1</type>
            <color>Green</color>
        </citem>
        <citem>
            <type>XX2</type>
            <color>Blue</color>
        </citem>
        <citem>
            <type>XX3</type>
            <color>Red</color>
        </citem>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

xml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderCatalog>
    <Product prodId="390">
        <Item colorDef='Yellow'>Tusk</Item>     
    </Product>
    <Product prodId="500">      
        <Item colorDef='Yellow'>Dowel</Item>        
    </Product>
</OrderCatalog>
```

Needed output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product prodId="390">
        <FavType>XX2</FavType>
        <citem>
            <type>XX1</type>
            <color>Green</color>
        </citem>
        <citem>
            <type>XX2</type>
            <color>Yellow</color>
        </citem>
        <citem>
            <type>XX3</type>
            <color>Red</color>
        </citem>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Code, that currently solves the first requirmnet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:param name="f1" select="'xml20.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="OrderCatalog/Product" use="@prodId"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Products/Product/citem" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="../@prodId"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
                <color>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/Item/@colorDef"/>
                </color>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is the preferred solution?
Nested for-each?

**Update:**
New XSL from the answer bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:param name="f1" select="'x20.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="OrderCatalog/Product" use="@prodId"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Products/Product/citem[type=../FavType]/color" >
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="../../@prodId"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/Item/@colorDef"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in case prodid in xml1 doesn't exist in xml2, I am getting this:

```
 <citem>
     <type>XX2</type>
     <color/>
  </citem>
```

instead of original

```
  <citem>
            <type>XX2</type>
            <color>Blue</color>
  </citem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to update 'color' node of 'xml1', with attribute 'colorDef' of
>   product element in 'xml2'

If you want to update only the `color`, why not have the template match it directly instead of its parent `citem`:

```
<xsl:template match="Products/Product/citem[type=../FavType]/color" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="../../@prodId"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/Item/@colorDef"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My bad, as always for simplicity, I present the basic example. But actually, I will be updating several elements under citem, ofcourse I can repeat the above but that won't be efficient.

Comment: "*I will be updating several elements under citem,*" So? Make templates for them too. Or, if you like, make a template for the specific `citem` (just remove the `/color` part from the match pattern above), then handle the children from there.

Comment: there is still an issue with this,
in case there is no matching prodId in xml2, then  'color' element with  matching 'FavType' is deleted!
Why doe it happen??

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce this problem. If there's no matching `prodId`in `xml2.xml`, then the matched `color` element will still be copied, though its string-value will be empty.

Comment: ,I updated my question with latest XSL, to reproduce the issue simply set in xml1, prodid that doesn't exist in second xml.

Comment: Well, you have `<color/>` in your output, so you cannot  say that the `color` element is deleted. -- As for why this is happening, it's because you asked for `<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/Item/@colorDef"/>` and that returns an empty string when there is no matching key. If you want to retain the original value in such case, you will have to use `xsl:choose` and test for the existence of a matching key first. Then decide if you want the looked up value or the existing one.